# Time Series: Why is my model giving predictions of lower variance?

Tags: time-series, model-selection

I have fit an MA(1) model (based on examining ACF and PACF) to a de-trended time series, which is stationary. I get the following result. The fitted values are closer to mean but with lower variance. Unless I difference this series, I am not able to get better fit. Why is it so?
[image]